# Canadian eTA for dual British and Canadian citizen with only British passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, uk-citizens, dual-nationality, eta

I am a dual Canadian and British citizen with only a British passport. The new Canadian immigration system requires British citizens to have an eTA (Electronic travel authorization) however you can not apply for one if you are a Canadian citizen. Does this mean I can no longer visit Canada using my British passport and will have to get a Canadian passport? An eTA costs $7 and a passport $160.

Comment: Do you have any other document that proves your Canadian citizenship?

Comment: If, presumedly, the OP is in the UK they need to fly to Canada and while the border guard might accept all sorts of documents the airlines might not. It's (way) easier to get a passport.

Comment: Do you have other proof of Canadian citizenship?